# Moodle Moove Child Theme

Tags: themes, parent-child, moodle, child-theming

I am trying to make a child theme for 'Moove' in moodle 3.6! But as soon as I update my database and click on theme selector button, I get an HTTP 500 error!

I follow the instruction from the blog below, but apparently, I am doing something wrong. Can sb help me please?

https://edwiser.org/blog/create-child-theme-moodle/

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 usually means there is something wrong in your scripts/configuration.
First thing to do would be to enable debugging messages to see what exactly is wrong.
Here you can find how to enable debug output to get more detailed error messages: https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Debugging#In_config.php